# How to convert List<decimal> to List<string>?

Tags: c#

My question is part of this problem:

I recieve a collection of id's from a form. I need to get the keys, convert them to string and pass it to the db.

```
 using (var db = new DbAmsecEntities())
 {
    cashsafelist = (from safe in db.Cashsafes
                    where safe.StoreId == (decimal)Convert.ToInt64(ddlLocationLists.SelectedValue)
                    select safe.CashsafeId).ToList();
    cashsafevalues = cashsafelist.Select(x => x.ToString).ToList();//getting error here
 }
```

Comment: Tried adding brackets to the `x.ToString()` call? For future reference, please try to detail the error you are getting and what attempts you have made to fix it; this makes the question better quality.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What error are you getting? Based on what the problem actually is, the error message should be a pretty big clue.

Comment: toString need brackets --> `ToString()`

Comment: Why convert to Int64 and then cast to decimal, use Convert.ToDecimal instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use **()**  in [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx)

```
cashsafevalues = cashsafelist.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Or: cashsafelist.Select(ToString).ToList();

Comment: @Dennis_E: than won't compile since `ToString` is not static.

Comment: @TimSchmelter being static has nothing to do with it. Can't you do that with an instance method??? On mono, I get the message it cannot infer the type, so that's why it fails. (I don't have access to a Windows machine right now, so I can't check if this is mono only). When you write a lambda like that, Resharper will hint to change it to a method group, because the x => x is redundant.

Comment: @Dennis_E: you're right, whether it is  `static` or not is not the only factor that matters. I must admit that i'm not sure how to get it to work with non-static methods but it must work somehow. That's why i've asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908548/how-to-use-existing-method-instead-of-lambda-when-its-not-static) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`List.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which was available since 2.0.

```
cashsafevalues = cashsafelist.ConvertAll<string>(d => d.ToString());
```

It *can* be more efficient than `ToList` because the list will be initialized with the correct size.