# How to use existing method instead of lambda when it's not static?

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, type-conversion

This must be a duplicate but i haven't found it. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841990/are-there-any-benefits-to-using-a-c-sharp-method-group-if-available) which is related since it answers why it's recommended to use a method group instead of a lambda.

But how do i use an existing method group instead of a lambda if the method is not in the current class and the method is not `static`?

Say i have a list of ints which i want to convert to strings, i can use `List.ConvertAll`, but i need to pass a `Converter<int, string>` to it:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> { 1 };
List<string> strings = ints.ConvertAll<string>(i => i.ToString());
```

This works, but it creates an unnecessary anonymous method with the lambda. So if `Int32.ToString` would be static and would take an `int` i could write:

```
List<string> strings = ints.ConvertAll<string>(Int32.ToString);
```

But that doesn't compile - of course. So how can i use a method group anyway?

If i'd  create an instance method like this

```
string FooInt(int foo)
{
    return foo.ToString();
}
```

i could use `strings = ints.ConvertAll<string>(FooInt);`, but that is not what i want. I don't want to create a new method just to be able to use an existing.

Comment: "This works, but it creates an unnecessary anonymous method with the lambda."  - So? what is the problem? It's even better, because the code of that lambda tells you exactly what is does - which enhance readability and therefore maintainability.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: that's also my opinion, but ReSharper suggests to use the method instead of the redundant lambda. So i've asked this question even if it might be premature optimization. I'm asking just out of curiosity. Also, `Int32.ToString` is not that difficult to understand (if it would work).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sounds like resharper got it wrong. You can replace the code with `ints.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList()` which would do exactly the same. Wondering if resharper would except that.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: that is exactly what i don't want. The LINQ query uses an anonymous method instead of `Int32.ToString`. Resharper would not like it (but i don't have it anyway).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I know it does, and sorry for not being clear on what I was intended: Because that (complaining about lambdas) is a strange behavior on the part of resharper, I was wondering if that would change things to resharper. Now, because lambdas are idiomatic to LINQ, it would even make some sense.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: maybe resharper doesn't even complain in this case, since i don't own it i cannot check it. But someone [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23906611/284240) it because resharper told him and i've heard it often before. I answered him that it's not possible because `ToString` isn't static, but i wasn't sure if that's true.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Now I understand. And I even think we both agree on that readability is most important, while micro-optimizations are worthless. :)

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: it's not only readability, you can also change a lambda easily, for example reverse a condition: `chars.Count(c => !Char.IsDigit(c))` whereas this method cannot be changed.

Comment: In Hebrew we have a saying that is something like this "You're convincing the convinced" :)

Answer (score 7):

There is an static method in the framework, that can be used to convert any integrated data type into a string, namely `Convert.ToString`:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> { 1 };
List<string> strings = ints.ConvertAll<string>(Convert.ToString);
```

Since the signature of `Convert.ToString` is also known, you can even eliminate the explicit target type parameter:

```
var strings = ints.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString);
```

This works. However, I'd also prefer the lambda-expression, even if ReSharper tells you something different. ReSharper sometimes optimizes too much imho. It prevents developers from thinking about their code, especially in the aspect of readability.

### Update

Based on Tim's comment, I will try to explain the difference between lambda and static method group calls in this particular case. Therefor, I first took a look into the `mscorlib` disassembly to figure out, how int-to-string conversion exactly works. The `Int32.ToString` method calls an external method within the `Number`-class of the `System` namespace:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries"), SecuritySafeCritical]
public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return Number.FormatInt32(this, null, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

The static `Convert.ToString` member does nothing else than calling `ToString` on the parameter:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static string ToString(int value)
{
    return value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Technically there would be no difference, if you'd write your own static member or extension, like you did in your question. So what's the difference between those two lines?

```
ints.ConvertAll<string>(i => i.ToString());
ints.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString);
```

Also - technically - there is no difference. The first example create's an anonymous method, that returns a string and accepts an integer. Using the integer's instance, it calls it's member `ToString`. The second one does the same, with the exception that the method is not anonymous, but an integrated member of the framework.

The only difference is that the second line is shorter and saves the compiler a few operations.

**But why can't you call the non-static `ToString` directly?**

Let's take a look into the `ConvertAll`-method of `List`:

```
public List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (converter == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.converter);
    }

    List<TOutput> list = new List<TOutput>(this._size);

    for (int i = 0; i < this._size; i++)
    {
        list._items[i] = converter(this._items[i]);
    }

    list._size = this._size;
    return list;
}
```

The list iteraterates over each item, calls the converter with the item as an argument and copys the result into a new list which it returns in the end.

So the only relation here is your `converter` that get's called explicitly. If you could pass `Int32.ToString` to the method, the compiler would have to decide to call `this._items[i].ToString()` within the loop. In this specific case it would work, but that's "too much intelligence" for the compiler. The type system does not support such code conversions. Instead the converter is an object, describing a method that can be called from the scope of the callee. Either this is an existing static method, like `Convert.ToString`, or an anonymous expression, like your lambda.

**What causes the differences in your benchmark results?**

That's hard to guess. I can imagine two factors:

1. Evaluating lambdas may result in runtime-overhead.
2. Framework calls may be optimized.

The last point especially means, that the JITer is able to inline the call which results in a better performance. However, those are just assumptions of mine. If anyone could clarify this, I'd appreciate it! :)

Comment: Yeah, I find method group conversions to be confusing as well. The error messages also aren't that good.

Comment: For a hundreds of $ product - this is just shame

Comment: The answer was not meant as bashing, because there are things, ReSharper can do better than VS. However, as of most tools, you need to know how to use it right and when it might be missleading to listen on it. That's what I meant by *it prevents developers from thinking about their code*. Personally I stopped using ReSharper to have more control over my personal code quality. Team feedback is more important than ReSharper feedback.

Comment: So the answer is: _no, it's not possible to use a non-static method that you don't "own"_? I normally agree that readability is most important but sometimes you need the most effcicient way, all the more if the complexity is hidden in (extension) methods. I also don't find `ConvertAll(Convert.ToString)` difficult to understand. Btw, i don't even own resharper, i just wanted to know _how it works_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: if *own* means *call a member within scope*, then you're right. That's the "nature" of C# - non-static members can only be called per-instance. Either you use them together with lambdas, or you write your own static (note: also internal extensions are possible!) members that perform the conversion. But what's the difference to using lambdas then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - lambdas and anonymous methods aren't less efficient. The compiler just create a class with those methods, and create a delegate for them (and that delegate is necessary anyway). About the indirection in calling to `ToString` - that would be inlined, so it is a non-issue too.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: so it doesn't matter how large the list is(in my example) since only one anonymous method is created? But it would matter if this code is executed in a loop. I just wanted to know if it's possible. In this case `System.Convert` does the trick, but  just because `int` is supported. So my example was bad.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - No it would not. The anonymous/lambda method is created once, in compile time. What would slightly matter are variables which used in closure, and declared *inside* the loop. And in any case (anonymous method or not) - a delegate would be created in any iteration of the loop.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: i have tested it with a loop(1M iterations). The method was considerably faster than the lambda(0.25 vs. 0.44 sec). I took the time with `StopWatch` and the simple method i used as test case was: `chars.Count(c => Char.IsDigit(c));`(`Char.IsDigit` in the method version) where `chars` was a `List<char>` with 6 characters. But i still agree that this is premature optimization in most cases.

Comment: Btw, the difference increases disproportionately, if it's called 10 times more: 1.6 sec.(method) vs. 3.4 sec.(lambda).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I've updated the answer... That's all I could find out on this :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I bet that you compiled in debug mode and let it ran inside the debugger. When testing in release mode, outside of the debugger, they are the same

Comment: @Shlomi: whoops, you're right, shame on me. The difference is clearly smaller in release (between 1.7 vs. 2.3  and 2.0 vs. 2.2 for 10M iterations).

Comment: @TimSchmelter And if you'll run it without debugging (ctrl+f5), the result would be the same (actually, it may fluctuate with no [preference/trend/bias/I don't know the word] for any of them.

Comment: @Aschratt: many thanks for your efforts. I'll accept the/an answer later.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: no, the difference remains. I'm writing the result in a text-file and start the app with `ctrl+F5`,  first three results: `lambda: 00:00:02.0148356
method: 00:00:01.6915965
lambda: 00:00:02.0950926
method: 00:00:01.6211572
lambda: 00:00:02.0371050
method: 00:00:01.6675659`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't have your code. When I tested it (unfortunately, inside a closed network, so I cannot send the code :( ), there where no deference (I didn't tested `Convert.ToString`, but using a static method, and lambda).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, because my result fluctuated around the hundredths of a second, I added 2 zeroes to the loop counter... Now I can really say that they are the same (still fluctuating around the hundredths of a second - which is meaningless for a 20-seconds run)

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: nevermind, i've deleted the ideone-link where the method-approach was slower. Let's keep it that way :)

Answer (score 3):

You hit the nail on the head yourself:

> This works, but it creates an **unnecessary** anonymous method with the
>   lambda.

You can't do what you're asking for because there is no appropriate method group that you can use so the anonymous method is **necessary**.  It works in that other case because the implicit range variable is **passed to** the delegate created by the method group.  In your case, you need the method to be **called on** the range variable.  It's a completely different scenario.

Comment: I think this hits the point well. Difference between _calling an instance method on instance_ and _passing an instance to the static method_ is the key.